Bounded linear functional with specific values at linearly independent vectors
Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. Let $\operatorname{dim}(E) = n < \infty$. Given $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ linearly independent vectors and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ scalars we can always construct a linear functional $\varphi: E\to \Bbb{F}$ such that $\varphi(x_j) = a_j$. Since $E$ is finite dimensional, this linear functional is continuous (and bounded).
Now, let $\operatorname{dim}(E) =  \infty$, $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ linearly independent vectors and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ scalars. Is it possible to construct a continuous (and bounded) linear functional $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(x_j) = a_j$?
Edit
My attempt: let $M = \operatorname{span}\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. Let $\phi:M \to \Bbb{F}$ such that $\phi(x_j) = a_j$ for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Since $\|\cdot\|:E\to \Bbb{F}$ restricted to $M$ is a norm in $M$ and $M$ is finite-dimensional, there exist $C>0$ such that
$$\|x\|_1 \leq C \|x\|,$$
where $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n|\alpha_j|$, where $x = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j x_j$. Moreover, given $x\in M$
$$|\phi(x)| \leq \max\{|a_j|\}\|x\|_1 \leq C\max\{|a_j|\}\|x\|.$$
Let $p:E \to \Bbb{F}$ such that $p(x) = C\max\{|a_j|\}\|x\|$. Then

$p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y), \quad \forall x, y \in E$,
$p(\alpha x) = |\alpha|p(x), \quad \forall x \in E, \alpha\in\Bbb{F}$.

Moreover, $\phi(x) \leq p(x)$ and $\phi$ is continuous. So, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists $\varphi:E\to\Bbb{F}$ such that

$\varphi(x) = \phi(x), \quad \forall x\in M$,
$\varphi(x) \leq p(x), \quad \forall x \in E$.

So $\varphi$ is continuous and in particular, $\varphi(x_j) = a_j$, for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Is it right?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Continuous_extension_theorem

@SassatelliGiulio, I tried to use Hahn Banach Theorem. I eddited my question. Is it right?

I don't know. The proof of the general version of what you ask is a couple of lines below the specific section of the page I've given you the link to. Compare that with yours and see for yourself.

Yes, your proof is correct.

Thanks! @DavidGao
